# browsing is not detecting code changes after npm run serve

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vue-cli, npm-scripts

I have installed vue-cli (4.4.6). To run the project i am using "npm run serve".
So, whenever I am doing any change in my code the npm compile the code but on browser changes are not reflecting on refreshing the page.  Its working only when I am using new tab. Is there any fix for this issue?

Comment: Maybe try to refresh with ctrl + f5 to refresh cache (Chrome)

Comment: On Chrome there's also an option to disable javascript cache when the developer tools are open, I personally always keep that one checked.

Comment: are you using wsl?